# Can I live in Germany with my blue card while working remotely for a company in Switzerland?

Tags: germany, blue-card, switzerland

I am Brazilian and I got a German blue card 8 months ago. I am considering changing jobs and working remotely for a company in Switzerland.

I know that I can change to a German job as long as I go to the registration office and provide them with proof of my new job. But can I do that with a job in another country? Considering that I will remain living in Germany?